# Value view/modification window

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm working with plots and I want to call a PySimpleGUI window on a press of a TK button which will show my plot tuples and allow modifying them to later re-draw the plot. So far I took [this cookbook example](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-list-comprehension-to-build-rows-table-simulation-grid-of-inputs) and added a save button:

```
layout += [[sg.Button('Save')]]
```

This is how I call it:

```
def readWindow(event):
    values = window.read()
    print(values)
editButton.on_clicked(readWindow)
```

and it successfully passes values when I click "save". But if I close the window and try to open it again, I get `(None, None)` in the console.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need tkinter Button.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# layout = ...
layout += [[sg.Button("Save", ...]]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Save":
        print(event, values)

window.close()
```